# Issue in UTF-8 in GlassFish 4.0

Tags: java, jsp, unicode, utf-8, glassfish

I have a JSP page where the user can input unicode characters and the server has to store those unicode characters properly into the SQL Server database.

My code in which I set **page encoding in JSP** and **character encoding in a filter** used to work perfectly in **Apache Geronimo**. However, when I deploy the same code in **GlassFish 4.0**, it started storing "?" in the database.

I followed the instructions given in [this blog post](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest) and added **parameter-encoding** tag in **glassfish-web.xml** and also added **jsp-config** in **web.xml**

and in my Servlet i am converting the input to UTF as **new String([Parameter].getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")** Here it gives me  **?**

I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong. Please suggest a workaround.

Comment: Check that your database connection string says `useUnicode=true`

Comment: Is that possible with SQL Server? I am not using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@developerwjk Thank you for the hint. There is a property **SendStringParametersAsUnicode** in **Additional Properties** of **JDBC Connection Pool**. This we have to set to **true**.

In fact, after doing this, it is working with out above said entries in **web.xml** and **glassfish-web.xml**.